# How do I generically loop through input elements in a form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates, client-side-validation

I'm trying to loop through the input elements in a form using jQuery so that I can do some lightweight client-side validation.  I'm using Django to generate the pages server side and the problem I'm having is that the particular page has many forms dynamically generated so I don't know the id of them before hand.  If I did I could easily do the validation.

So in my javascript I'm trying to capture the submit action of the form and when that's found, somehow get the input elements so that I can check the parameters.  Here's what I've tried amongst other things:

```
$(".s-inputs").submit(function(event){      
  $(this).filter(':input').each(function(){
    console.log("Doesn't work");
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried including the django code that generates the html forms below but something in the templating system was throwing off Stack Overflow's formatting of it.  I don't think it would have been very instructive anyway.  Essentially my html is just an arbitrary number of forms on the page each with an arbitrary number of inputs, all dynamically generated server side.  The only thing they share in common is the class "s-inputs."

Thanks for any help.

Comment: also include the partial html you are selecting

Comment: It's essentially any number of generic <forms> enclosing any number of <inputs>, the number of which I don't know ahead of time.  I can assign them all the same class, and I can give them each a unique ID using django's facilities, but I don't know how many will be generated so I can't hard code in the javascript those IDs.  I need a generic and programatic way to loop over the inner inputs in the forms that respond to the jquery .submit() function.  See here for an example form with inputs: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rxwwoo2a/)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find()`, not `filter()`:

```
$(this).find(':input').each(function(){
  console.log("Doesn't work");
});
```

`filter()` attempts to filter the currently selected element(s) (which is currently just your `form` element) and remove anything which isn't what is being filtered on. This will return nothing, as your `form` element isn't matched by `:input`.

`find()` on the other hand searches for any matching selector contained within the currently selected elements. This will match any matching `:input` element contained within your `form`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Changing it to find makes some progress.  Now I get a message logged to console.  However, only one message gets logged and there are two inputs inside of that form.  How come it is only looping once when there are two inputs?  Please see this for what my generated HTML looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/rxwwoo2a/  Thanks.